# Given this protocol, can you find some weakness?

Tags: symmetric

```
1) A->B  A||B||{Na}Kab
2) B->A  {Na+1,Nb}Kab
3) A->B  {Nb+1}Kab
4) B->A  {K'ab,N'b}Kab
```

This protocol is used to refresh a symmetric session key.

EDIT:

`A` and `B` are the IDs of users A and B.
`Na`, `Nb`, `N'b` are nonces (pseudorandom values).
`Kab` is the old session key.
`K'ab` is the new session key.
`||` means concatenation.

An attacker is only able to do man-in-the-middle.
Every message is encrypted with `Kab`

Comment: First, you might want to explain your notation, because it's not clear. And then explain the initial settings (e.g. who knows what) **and** what kind of attacker model you have in mind.

Comment: Are messages 2 and 3 encrypted somehow?

Comment: The protocol is effectively the same as this one-step protocol: $1) B\rightarrow A : \{K'_{ab}\}_{K_{ab}}$. The exchange of nonces doesn't do anything.

Comment: @mikeazo I forgot the encryption on messages 2 and 3. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

One weakness with this protocol is that the compromise of a past symmetric key, which can often be assumed over some sufficiently large period of time, compromises all keys and messages sent after the time that key was first used.

edit:

If any $K_{ab}$ is compromised, a man in the middle attacker can resend message 4 corresponding to the compromised $K_{ab}$ and it will be accepted by $A$. The attacker can then impersonate $B$ communicating using the compromised key.